# Error: Cannot find module '@vuejs/plugin-vue'

Tags: php, laravel

PS C:\Users\aliha\desktop\projects\vue+laravel\invoice-three-app> npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\aliha\desktop\projects\vue+laravel\invoice-three-app\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
***Error: Cannot find module '@vuejs/plugin-vue'***
Require stack:

- C:\Users\aliha\desktop\projects\vue+laravel\invoice-three-app\vite.config.js
- C:\Users\aliha\Desktop\Projects\Vue+Laravel\invoice-three-app\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-5cb728cb.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\aliha\desktop\projects\vue+laravel\invoice-three-app\vite.config.js:33:33)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object._require.extensions. [as .js] (file:///C:/Users/aliha/Desktop/Projects/Vue+Laravel/invoice-three-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5cb728cb.js:63005:24)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm i @vuejs/plugin-vue
```